# Will get good traffic from Google if I pull content via RSS feeds?

Tags: seo, google-search, automation, google

Now-a-days, There are many plugins available in Wordpress to perform Auto Post / blogging. I know it grabs content from RSS feeds and posts it to our blog. Some of the Premium plugin will grabs full content from other sites and post it to our blog.

But, I do not know how the Google search engine treats such blogs (copied content.)
Will it give good traffic to such blogs?
Will it give copyright related issues?

Any suggestions and ideas for the above points?

Answer (score 4):

No. You will not get good rankings. This is duplicate content which is what exactly what Google doesn't want. Don't expect good rankings. In fact, don't be surprised if your entire site is penalized for being very low quality content. Basically, this is a waste of time.

Comment: Agreed, but if the content is useful to your readers go ahead and use it, but be sure to set the rel canonical tag to the site of origin. That way Google recognizes that you're not trying to leverage someone else's content for SEO gains, just for information purposes. This will not help your SEO rankings but it will also avoid a penalty.

Answer (score 2):

Syndicated content, strictly speaking, won't hurt you. Google will attempt to find the best match for a search and that URL will get preference in the rankings so you may not get the results you want. And [there are ways to syndicate properly](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/12/handling-legitimate-cross-domain.html).

I have no idea if these unnamed plugins are in any way compliant with those syndication guidelines. Even if they do syndication right the originating source will get the rank, not your site, which makes me suspect that they don't do syndication right.

However, as several people have already said, Google does not like to see an excessive volume of duplicated content and that sounds like exactly what you are thinking about doing. Cheap, easy content gets you nothing at best and gets you penalized an worst.

Comment: i agree your point. Most of good traffic NEWS publishing web sites are buying contents from news source and publishing it by simply editing their titles only. what is your suggestion on this?

Comment: Try the sentence "Obama takes oath, with gala to follow today" in google search result. You will get results with lots of duplicated websites. But all listed sites still getting huge traffic that i knew. Please suggest on this.

Comment: Click through those results. Most of them are not carbon copies of a single article. They are headline only links or short excerpts that point back to (looks like) a Boston Globe article, which is top of the list. They seem to be doing what people here are telling you to do. Search for something deeper in the article like "Biden’s service was attended by his family, top administration officials, and several longtime aides." and you will see that there is really only one source for this.

Answer (score 1):

Google penalize massive amounts of duplicate content.

Publishing headlines from various RSS-feeds in a sidebar will not hurt you.  However, if significant parts of your site is made up of content pulled from RSS (or scraped from another sites), Google will lower your PageRank, making you not appear on the SERP.

Publishing an RSS stream means that there is implicit permission for others to syndicate the content, but you're still obliged to acknowledge the source of such content.  If you acknowledge the source, you should have no problems with copyright when using content from a RSS-stream.

Answer (score 1):

Google massively penalizes such sites. In addition to this, you can run into copyright issues. Since Google slaps a duplicate content penalty, the original author of copied content HAVE to prevent their content from appearing elsewhere.

For example, my site has an RSS feed. Sometimes sites with the type of plug-ins you're talking about, pull content from my site using the feed and I end up having to file DMCA and cease & desist letters. Oftentimes, the admin is non-responsive, so I end up filing with the host. Sometimes hosts end up pulling the whole site down.

This can result in a big mess for admins (and the original authors), so I would STRONGLY advise against pulling articles/content from other sites via RSS.

Comment: In response to Melanie: The whole idea of RSS is to Syndicate Content! So why do you file DMCA's against publisher who publish your content??? If you don't want people to syndicate (RSS: Real Simple Sydication!) just don't have a rss stream on your website!

Answer (score 0):

No you won't, in fact you might very well get banned from the search results.

It's simple, Google values real content by real people.

Answer (score 0):

I think Google not ban sites with Rss feed news,if you use only title from other sites.He ban site or adsense if you copy whole content(grab with rss feed) for example:description